# PC was starting intermittently but now doesn't boot at all

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios, nvidia-graphics-card

I bought a custom laptop (PC Specialist Vortex IV, based on the Clevo P170SM-A) around a year ago and recently started having issues. First there was no display appear at all after powering on. Just a black screen, didn't even show the BIOS splash screen. It was intermittent to start with (if you powered it off then on again a few times it would display) but then didn't appear to work at all after a week or two. I tried using an external monitor but nothing displayed on this either. When it did display, everything would work without any issue. If you put the PC in sleep mode rather than shutting down, the display would still work after waking it up. Even though you only got a blank screen it still appeared to boot up and I was able to log in to windows (typing in the password blind). I can tell it logged in as you got the log in chime and upgrade notifications coming through the audio

I tried removing either one of the RAM modules and using each on it's own but still had the same issue. I then removed and reinserted the CMOS battery but this made it worse. It then started beeping every time the PC was turned on (two short then long continuous beeps until shutting down, according to AMI beep codes it's a memory issue of some kind) with still no display appearing

I then removed the GPU card and it goes to the splash screen where you can go to BIOS setup or boot options. However after a few seconds it starts beeping again (long continuous beeps with the caps/screen lock LEDs blinking as well) but you can still go into either the setup or boot options and do anything in there fine. I cleaned the connections and tried reseating the GPU card but got the same issue as before (no display with two short beeps then continuous beeps)

Anyone have any idea what the issue may be or how to fix it? I thought it may be the GPU but not sure seeing as it still beeps after removing it. Otherwise might be the motherboard but not sure what else to check for this. Had a look for something obvious like blown capacitors or loose connections but didn't see anything. If there's anything else I can do to help diagnose the issue then please let us know, any help would be much appreciated

Specs:

Chassis: Clevo P170SM-A, CPU: i7-4710MQ (2.5GHz) , RAM: 16GB DDR3, GPU: GTX980M-8G, BIOS: AMI, OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was clearly with something related to display because, as you mentioned, the PC was booting normally since you were able to interact with Windows but there is no display.

It might've been the GPU. What supports that is you could display the BIOS screen when you removed the GPU. Also you tried both native and external screen but got the same problem.

Are you still able to boot up Windows? looks like you couldn't after the recent changes (CMOS reset etc.).

So just to make sure, try removing both RAM modules and open BIOS as it might be a compatibility issue (happened to me personally). Try that with all components. Try installing a different GPU. See if there is an option in BIOS to view hardware status. You should also be able to find the list of components (especially RAM and GPU) compatible with your motherboard on the official motherboard website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After the CMOS reset it changed the BIOS settings to default which had UEFI boot disabled so it wasn't going to Windows. Enabling it again booted into Windows OK (with GPU still removed), although it still beeps and resets the PC after about 30 seconds. I tried removing either of the RAM modules but the PC was still beeping, removing both didn't boot at all

Comment: Also I couldn't see an option for hardware status in the BIOS screens. I don't have a spare GPU for this laptop model at the moment but I'll try and  get one as it seems like the no display issue is likely GPU related anyway. Not sure about the current beeping/reseting though

Comment: Of course it will not boot without the RAM because Windows will have no place to load. I wanted you to remove both and go directly to BIOS. The purpose is to check if the beeping and reset stops or not.

Comment: Does your motherboard have an integrated display card? If yes then use it until you buy a new GPU. You can also go to a repair shop and let them test a spare GPU to assure where the problem is and then get a replacement. Good luck.

Comment: When I removed both RAM modules I was unable to get to the BIOS screen, the display stays off after powering on. It still beeps if the RAM modules are removed as well (same continuous beeps for ~30 seconds). The motherboard does have an integrated GPU so I get things displaying if the card is taken out at least. I'll have to call up repair shops and see if they have any spare compatible GPU cards. Not sure if they'll have one but worth checking for sure